# Get the actual value use by MySQL after a mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an web application working. I use that piece of code that do work:

```
$dbConnection = getDbConnection();
    $stmt =  mysqli_prepare( $dbConnection, $SQLStatement);
    $bindParamArray = array_merge(array($stmt, $SQLBindString), $bindValueArray );
    call_user_func_array ( mysqli_stmt_bind_param , $bindParamArray );

    if( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ) {
        $ret = mysqli_insert_id ($dbConnection);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        $dbConnection->close();
    }else{
        //echo "<br><br>statement : ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        $dbConnection->close();
    }
```

Well I'd like to know how php is casting the value send to db when binding value, and I'm looking to a way to get the binded actual value in the db before statement is executed to check if there's differences between the original values and the binded values.

For example if you try to bind an empty string inside an INTEGER it will put the value `0` or if you put the date `2013-15-15` (a non-exiting date obviously) it wil cast it to `0000-00-00` and it's definitly not the behaviour I'm expecting.

Is there any to accomplish what I want ?

Comment: I think that if you insert an incorrect date it has nothing to do with the binding, but is a problem for MySQL -- and it will emit a warning.

Comment: @ExplosionPills problem is I don't want to insert value and then know there have been a warning I want to know what value will be used by MySQL as I heard php is doing the casting I though it was possible

Comment: I don't think that PHP does anything with the date.  It may cast the integer, though .. probably using something akin to `intval`

Comment: in case of the date I insure you that in the end I get a 0000-00-00 inserted inside my db and I prefer to get an error instead of that :D

Comment: I know you do, but it's MySQL that is doing that, not PHP.  Try running this from the MySQL command line: `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-15-15'))`

Comment: well it gives me the first date possible in Mysql db not `0000-00-00` Can they be considered the same ?